# Geodesics is a connected graph. (Ex. 1.16 in A First Course in Graph Theory by Chartrand and Zhang)

Tags: graph-theory, geodesic

The problem I am trying to solve is the following.

> Let $P = (u=v_0,v_1, \cdots ,v_k = v),k\geq 1$,be a $u-v$ geodesic in a connected graph $G$. Prove that $d(u,v_i) = i$ for each integer $i$ with $1\leq i\leq k$.

My proof is as follows.

> Notice that since $P$ is a geodesic, $d(u,v) = k.$ Now, $d(u,v_i)\leq i$ since there exists a walk with distance $i$ and thus a path with distance at most $i$. However, if $d(u,v_i)<i$, then this would imply that $P$ is not minimal, a contradiction. Thus, $d(u,v_i)=i$.

Could someone check my proof for me, or maybe provide me with hints on how to correct my proof? Or is there a better/faster proof out there that someone could share with me?

Comment: Seems fine by me. I don't think there is a more direct proof to be found.

Comment: I think the third sentence could be expounded on a bit. Why does it imply that $P$ is not minimal? What would a shorter path from $u$ to $v$ be? Note that this depends on whether $v_j$ is in the shorter path from $u$ to $v_i$, where $j>i$.